# is exec statement needed to run sql procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, exec

This is the procedure that i have created

```
     QUERY_EMP(EID IN  employees.employee_id%TYPE,JID OUT employees.job_id%TYPE,SAL OUT employees.salary%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT   JOB_ID,SALARY
    INTO       JID,SAL
    FROM     employees
    WHERE   employee_id = EID;
COMMIT;
END;
```

if i run the procedure using following :

```
    emp_id      employees.employee_id%TYPE; 
    emp_salary  employees.salary%TYPE; 
    emp_job_id  employees.job_id%TYPE; 
begin    
emp_id := 103; 
QUERY_EMP(emp_id,emp_job_id,emp_salary); 
dbms_output.put_line('For: ' || emp_id ); 
dbms_output.put_line('Salary: ' || emp_salary); 
dbms_output.put_line('Job Id: ' || emp_job_id); 
end;
```

i get the following error
[encountered exec query instead of symbols =@:(%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4XyR.png)

but if I run without writing exec before the procedure it runs. So why is exec command not needed here and what is the use of begin and end here?

Comment: oracle live SQL since it's a college assignment. there is no mention of this in LiveSQL documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'exec' (or 'execute') is a *sqlplus* command.  It is used to tell *sqlplus* to ask the server to execute the given procedure.  You are working with a PL/SQL block, and there is no 'exec' command in pl/sql.  PL/SQL *does* have the 'execute immediate' command, for executing dynamic sql, but 'execute' and 'execute immediate' are not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. can you explain why begin and end is required before and after  running the stored procedure.do you know any good source from where I can learn this ?I had used execute for another procedure in same assignment and it ran without errors .that procedure didn't have any out parameters

Comment: BEGIN and END define the BEGINing and ENDing of a PL/SQL block.  Where to learn?  Start with the docs:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/index.html